# Secure RDS database connect credentials

Tags: scala, amazon-ec2, database-connection, credentials, amazon-rds

I'm looking around for quite some time and I'm still not sure, what the best practices for RDS credentials are. I want to connect from a EC2 instance to the RDS programmatically, I hardcoded the credentials in my "application.conf" at the moment (it works, but I think it's pretty bad).

I'm using Scala btw. Java would work for me aswell.

Is saving the credentials into a S3 bucket and download them the way to go like [this?](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx610S2MLVZWEA/Using-IAM-roles-to-distribute-non-AWS-credentials-to-your-EC2-instances)

Is [that](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx3D6U6WSFGOK2H/A-New-and-Standardized-Way-to-Manage-Credentials-in-the-AWS-SDKs) the way to go? Does that function for RDS credentials as well? If yes, how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

There's really nothing specific about RDS in your question. The question is really about how to store and retrieve strings securely. Those strings could be your database credentials or anything else.

There are multiple ways to do this, and there is not one "best" way that everyone recommends. You could set these values in a file or in environment variables in your EC2 instance, so that only processes running on the EC2 server would have access. Or you could look into using the AWS KMS service to store these values. Or you could store them in a properties file in S3 like in the link you posted. I'm sure there are lots of other methods for doing this.